# AWS find instance by public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have weird problem and it will be really hard to explain, but let me try :).

I've a site running in AWS EC2. I need to find the instance where my site is running/working.

I know which Security Group attached to my site. How I know is, I add/remove inbound ICMP rules and it effect the ping. But that Security Group doesn't assign to any EC2 instance.

I've also stopped all the EC2 instance but my site still working.

How it's possible, I don't really have any idea. Might be someone went into this same issue and have solution.

Looking forward...

Comment: That is certainly quite strange! How do you know that your Security Group isn't assigned to an EC2 instance -- where are you looking to confirm this? When you say "my site is still working", are you able to click links and process information, or might the site simply be cached in your web browser?

Comment: Under "Security Groups" column on instances list page.
No, there is not cached site. I can navigate and process the requests by filling forms.

Comment: An instance can have multiple security groups. If you are saying that modifying a security group is having an impact on the server, then the EC2 instance will be in the same VPC as the security group. You might also have more instances than are showing on one page. Check the arrows in the top-right to see if you have more instances than are showing.

Comment: Dashboard and list page showing total 11 instances. No navigation arrows activated, means no more records. _Is it possible that there are some hidden instances? If yes, how can we see those?_ I also check all regions but no instance found in any other regions.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. If you can modify the security group and it affects the instance, then it would be in the same VPC, in the same region, in your own account. I would recommend you contact AWS Support, who have access to services used in your account.

Comment: @Haroon you should first check where your domain forwards to by `dig www.yourdomain.com`

Comment: Have you checked all regions and verified your site isn't running in us-west-2 or another region?

Comment: Why dont you make an stress test against your site and monitor all your instances CPU? the one that has an spike is the winner :)

Comment: Is it not an EC2 instance?  Like maybe a Fargate container?  If you look in the EC2 console under Network Interfaces, you should be able to find the network adapter and work your way backwards.

Comment: Sorry to keep you engage in this guys. It was my clients bad, she doesn't even know what this is and at last she mentioned _we moved to elastic beans_ **bummer**. Thank you so much for your kind suggestions. I will use them in future.